# Socket.io Promise.all unexpected results

Tags: javascript, promise, socket.io

This is my socket.io server code and the socket.emit() function works as i am getting back the expected result, but the Promise.all function ruins the output. Below is the log of this application

```
socket.on('hh:broadcast', (props, cb) => {
        const session = sockets.get(socket);
        if (!session) return;
        const [room, that] = session;
        const collaborators = sessions.get(room)!;

        Promise.all<ArrayElement<NonNullable<Parameters<typeof cb>['0']>>>(collaborators
            .filter(([, other]) => other !== that)
            .map(([sock, other]) => sock
                .emitWithAck('hh:data', { id: that, ...props })
                .then(res => {
                    log.info("received", other, res);
                    return { id: other, ...res };
                }))
        ).then(res => {
            log.warn("Promise.all:", JSON.stringify(res))
            cb(res);
        });
   });
```

the log shows the result of the Promise.all, but it is not correct (only contains the emit of one client, not the rest, they are simply empty arrays) Why is that? I am getting back the correct result inside the promises, but the Promise.all can't merge these results into an array?

```
19:43:28.431 [WebSocket] received gDmNz9Ih2WWw {data: {data: [49, 237, 191, 23, 68, 120, 57, 163, 65, 57, 62, 200, 19, 155, 179, 23, 183, 242, 236, 97, 164, 99], type: "Buffer"}}
19:43:28.431 [WebSocket] received mX6SfA2F0MsD {data: {data: [49, 229, 183, 22, 72, 120, 202, 117, 249, 93, 17, 39, 226, 13, 101, 160, 208, 243, 76, 82, 95, 116], type: "Buffer"}}
19:43:28.431 [WARNING WebSocket] Promise.all: [{"id":"mX6SfA2F0MsD","data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[49,229,183,22,72,120,202,117,249,93,17,39,226,13,101,160,208,243,76,82,95,116]}},{"id":"gDmNz9Ih2WWw","data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[]}}]
```

Comment: It looks like the buffer is reused, and emptied at some point between logging it in the first `.then()` and all the (other) promises resolving and logging it in the second `.then()`. Try copying the buffer.

Comment: Also what exactly do you want to do with the results?

Comment: Yes, the arraybuffers behave SO weird. when logging them inside the .then() they exist, but outside, they are gone (or empty). I send the result back to the client as one single array so that it can process the data

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need to catch all errors to know if any connection is failing or not. Promise.all will be rejected as soon as any of the promises in the array rejected which is most probably your case. I think one of the promises array is being rejected causing the entire Promise.all to reject early.

I would also recommend using Promise.allSettled instead of Promise.all. We need to ensure that errors in individual promises don't prevent the other promises from resolving.

```
const promises = collaborators
    .filter(([, other]) => other !== that)
    .map(([sock, other]) =>
        sock.emitWithAck('hh:data', { id: that, ...props })
            .then(res => {
                log.info("received", other, res);
                return { id: other, ...res };
            })
            .catch(error => {
                log.error("Error from promise:", error);
                return null;
            })
    );

const results = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
```

Of course, you will need to filter results to get only the correct ones without errors out of the results array.

### Another way to solve the issue if you are still facing a problem

try the same concept but use async/await technique instead to handle the collaborators' requests one by one in a sync way to make it simpler. It may impact the performance a little bit negatively because of the sync way. However, it will help you to better understand what is going on:

```
socket.on('hh:broadcast', async (props, done) => {
  const session = sockets.get(socket);
  if (!session) return;
  const [room, that] = session;
  const collaborators = sessions.get(room)!;

  const results = [];

  for (const [sock, other] of collaborators) {
    if (other !== that) {
        try {
            const res = await sock.emitWithAck('hh:data', { id: that, ...props });
            log.info("received", other, res);
            results.push({ id: other, ...res });
        } catch (error) {
            log.error("Error from promise:", error);
            results.push({ id: other, error: true });
        }
    }
  }

  log.warn("Results:", JSON.stringify(results));
  done(results);
});
```

Comment: Just tested this, and the promise is not failing. I am getting the expected result inside the acknowledgement of the emit as the logs show, just the output of the Promise.all is not working. Handling errors is surely a thing to implement, but it did not solve the problem in my case.

Comment: My answer was updated to to use promise.allSettled instead of .all

Comment: Please try it then let me know

Comment: This is the log of results (https://pastebin.com/7dDHwKe7):
`[{status: "fulfilled", value: {data: {data: [234, 29, 127, 206, 167, 53, 26, 115, 166, 65, 227, 52, 60, 136, 106, 73, 188, 217, 118, 76, 221, 64], type: "Buffer"}, id: "uS0TCPICmUg0"}}, {status: "fulfilled", value: {data: Buffer [], id: "FY6sxTPZxNZj"}}]`

Comment: Sorry for all the instructions but it's not easy to diagnose such  an issue @Fabi

Comment: The question is updated with more instructions to solve the whole problem using async/await which will help us diagnose what is going on

Comment: You should use *either* `Promise.allSettled` *or* `.catch`, not both of them

Comment: "*ensure that errors in individual promises don't prevent the other promises from resolving*" - regardless whether you use `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled`, or something else, the individual promises **never** affect each other. The different ways to handle them only affect the `results`.

Comment: I agree with you. Im just trying to debug it with you. Did you try the await/Async solution?